# breadcrumb_url - Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to do breadcrumbs by this example https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1289/ but have error `Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`I did everything just like in this example. But I'm doing something wrong.

Error in this line `{% breadcrumb_url 'Home' product_list %}`

**urls.py**

```
app_name = 'shop'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    url(r'^show/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)$', views.product_show, name='product_show'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)$', views.product_list, name='lst_by_ctgry'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<subcategory>[-\w]+)$', views.product_list, name='lst_by_subctgry'),
    url(r'^(?P<category>[-\w]+)/(?P<subcategory>[-\w]+)/(?P<kind>[-\w]+)$', views.product_list, name='lst_by_knds'),
]
```

**base.html**

```
{% load breadcrumbs %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Shop</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block breadcrumbs %}
            {% breadcrumb_url 'Home' product_list %}
        {% endblock %}

        <div class="container">
            {% block content %} {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**breadcrumbs.py**

```
from django import template
from django.template import loader, Node, Variable
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_text
from django.template.defaulttags import url
from django.template import VariableDoesNotExist

register = template.Library()

@register.tag
def breadcrumb(parser, token):
    """
    Renders the breadcrumb.
    Examples:
        {% breadcrumb "Title of breadcrumb" url_var %}
        {% breadcrumb context_var  url_var %}
        {% breadcrumb "Just the title" %}
        {% breadcrumb just_context_var %}

    Parameters:
    -First parameter is the title of the crumb,
    -Second (optional) parameter is the url variable to link to, produced by url tag, i.e.:
        {% url person_detail object.id as person_url %}
        then:
        {% breadcrumb person.name person_url %}

    @author Andriy Drozdyuk
    """
    return BreadcrumbNode(token.split_contents()[1:])


@register.tag
def breadcrumb_url(parser, token):
    """
    Same as breadcrumb
    but instead of url context variable takes in all the
    arguments URL tag takes.
        {% breadcrumb "Title of breadcrumb" person_detail person.id %}
        {% breadcrumb person.name person_detail person.id %}
    """

    bits = token.split_contents()
    if len(bits)==2:
        return breadcrumb(parser, token)

    # Extract our extra title parameter
    title = bits.pop(1)
    token.contents = ' '.join(bits)

    url_node = url(parser, token)

    return UrlBreadcrumbNode(title, url_node)


class BreadcrumbNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, vars):
        """
        First var is title, second var is url context variable
        """
        self.vars = map(Variable,vars)

    def render(self, context):
        title = self.vars[0].var

        if title.find("'")==-1 and title.find('"')==-1:
            try:
                val = self.vars[0]
                title = val.resolve(context)
            except:
                title = ''

        else:
            title=title.strip("'").strip('"')
            title=smart_text(title)

        url = None

        if len(self.vars)>1:
            val = self.vars[1]
            try:
                url = val.resolve(context)
            except VariableDoesNotExist:
                print('URL does not exist', val)
                url = None

        return create_crumb(title, url)


class UrlBreadcrumbNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, title, url_node):
        self.title = Variable(title)
        self.url_node = url_node

    def render(self, context):
        title = self.title.var

        if title.find("'")==-1 and title.find('"')==-1:
            try:
                val = self.title
                title = val.resolve(context)
            except:
                title = ''
        else:
            title=title.strip("'").strip('"')
            title=smart_text(title)

        url = self.url_node.render(context)
        return create_crumb(title, url)


def create_crumb(title, url=None):
    """
    Helper function
    """
    crumb = """<span class="breadcrumbs-arrow">""" \
            """<img src="#" alt="Arrow">""" \
            """</span>"""
    if url:
        crumb = "%s<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (crumb, url, title)
    else:
        crumb = "%s&nbsp;&nbsp;%s" % (crumb, title)

    return crumb
```

Helps me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify `{% breadcrumb_url 'Home' product_list %}` it assumes `product_list` is a variable. Instead, you want to wrap it in quotes to say it is the name of the URL

`breadcrumb_url` takes the title followed by the same arguments you would have given to `url`. So since you would do

```
{% url 'shop:product_list' %}
```

The breadcrumb url becomes

```
{% breadcrumb_url 'Home' 'shop:product_list' %}
```

Comment: `{% breadcrumb_url 'Home' 'shop:product_list' %}` working for me, Thanks!)